# Parsing with class that's more than one word

Tags: php, html, parsing, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse this table (only part is shown):

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="row-item-all-0-1" class="my-day-menu-table" style="">
    <tr class="always-show-me">
        <td colspan="3"><strong>Dinner</strong></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="price- menu-item-type-1">
        <td width="24%" class="child-odd border-candidate station" style="vertical-align:top;" rowspan="1">
            <strong>options</strong>
        </td>
        <td class="child-odd description">
            <strong>pasta express</strong> <img class="tipbox vegetarian" src="http://www.cafebonappetit.com/images/public/menu-item-type-orange.png" alt="vegetarian" />
        </td>
        ...
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

I want to get the text "options" which has the class "child-odd border-candidate selection" but when I use Simple HTML Dom parser it doesn't seem to like it because the class is more than one word. How would I do this? Note I've tried putting the class name in quotes and it hasn't worked.

Comment: Just a note, that's not a class with multiple words, its a list of multiple classes.

Comment: "child-odd border-candidate selection" isn't a single class, it's four separate classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class isn't more than one word, it's separate classes. You should be able to pick up that element using Simple HTML DOM Parser this way:

```
$el = $html->find('div[class=child-odd border-candidate selection]');
```